# Radius of a Circle w/ Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> A circle with a random radius R∼Unif(0,1) is generated.  Let A be its area.
> (a) Find the mean and variance of A, without first finding the CDF or PDF of A.
> (b) Find the CDF and PDF of A.

So, quite obviously, we know the equation of a circle as A = ${\pi}r^2$. If we are given a uniform distribution, can we not just find E(R) and then, using that value, find E(A), and likewise for the variance? Is this allowed? And, if we have F(A), is this the CDF or PDF?

PLEASE help. Thanks!

Comment: You can evaluate $E(A)$ using the density function of $R$.

Comment: Understood, but I'm wondering how to evaluate it without the PDF/CDF.

Comment: In the question, you are not allowed to use the PDF of $A$, but you are allowed to use the PDF of $R$, which is sufficient.

Comment: So I'm then correct in saying that we can find the mean and variance of R (using simply the mean and variance of a uniform distribution), and plug that into pi r^2?

Comment: No. Instead, use the definition of expectation of a function of a random variable.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you have difficulty in finding $E[A]$ and $Var[A]$ without using the PDF of $A$.

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x)$, then for any real-valued function $g$,

$$E[g(X)] = \int_{x} g(x) f(x) dx$$

Since $A = \pi R^2$,

$$E[A] = E[\pi R^2] = \pi E[R^2]$$

$$E[R^2] = \int_{0}^{1} r^2 \cdot 1 \text{ }dr = \frac{1}{3}$$

So, $E[A] = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$.

$$E[A^2] = E[\pi^2R^4] = \pi^2E[R^4]$$
$$E[R^4] = \int_{0}^{1} r^4\cdot 1\text{ } dr = \frac{1}{5}$$
So, $E[A^2] = \dfrac{\pi^2}{5}$.

Hence, $Var[A] = E[A^2]-(E[A])^2 = \dfrac{\pi^2}{5} - \dfrac{\pi^2}{9} = \dfrac{4\pi^2}{45}$.

Comment: So then, given that g(x) = pi*r^2, can we simply integrate that to get the CDF?

Comment: Pls check the definition again in your course notes or textbook.